# C# - Creating a 16bit hex value

Tags: c#, hex, short

How can I write a 16bit(short) hex value?  0x0001 is 16 bits but defaults to an Int32.  The only way I have made this work is by converting between Int32 and Int16.

Here is some code that I must write:

```
short newValue = Convert.ToInt16(Convert.ToInt32(someObject.Value) | 0x0001);
```

Comment: Write to where?  Is this a string (text) problem?

Comment: Your question is missing some important context, making it hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps showing some code would help, even if you think the code is sub-optimal or non-working.

Comment: There is no syntax to state a numeric literal is a short if that's what your asking (i.e no 0x0001S)

Comment: If I simply type in 0x0001 and hover my cursor over it, it says it is an Int32.  If I wanted an Int32, I would've written 0x00000001.

Comment: To do that you would need a type suffix, 0x0001L is an int64 for example  but there is nothing for short.  Simply (short)0x0001

Comment: I edited my original message to add code.  Thank you Alex.  It sounds like the only way to do this is declare it explicitly like ASh posted.

Comment: This is the very old question about why `byte+byte = int`. It is the `|` that makes this an Int32, nothing you can do about that. Except maybe avoid using `short`, which usually is pointless anyway.

Comment: Note that "|" operator will convert both operands to int (or long) anyway, so there is no reason to cast.

Comment: Henk, I am not adding two numbers.  I am doing bitwise operations.

Comment: Doesn't matter.  The result of `short1 | short2`  is of type `int`

Comment: Thanks Henk.  I did not know it applied to bitwise operations too.

Comment: Better question: why is `newValue` of type `short` ? Is there a good reason for that?

Comment: Henk, I am interfacing to a PLC that uses 16 bit registers.  It sounds like it might be easier to just use INTs for everything instead though..

Comment: You can use ints until the last phase where result should really be of type `short` (say when you pass it to function which expects short). Or otherwise you will have to cast everywhere, but at least try to reduce amount of unnecessary casts, for example: `short newValue = (short) (someObject.Value | 0x0001)`